# Is there an elegant way to implement a clock-update event?

Tags: javascript, events, time

As far as I know (and I know relatively little), there is no native event that is emitted when e.g. the seconds hand ticks. The best I came up with is repeatedly checking a *Date* object (e.g. every 333ms; a shorter interval results in higher precision but is also more resource intensive). Somehow, if I use the same *Date* object over and over, time won't update, while

```
Date.prototype.getSeconds()
```

logs 'NaN' although *typeof* is 'number'.

```
    function clock(interval) {
    var d = new Date();
    var secondsOld = d.getSeconds();
    d = null;

    setInterval(function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var secondsNew = d.getSeconds();
        if ( secondsNew !== secondsOld ) {
            secondsOld = secondsNew;
            // trigger something
            console.log(secondsOld);
        }
        d = null;
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: You need to know the system date? Because if not, you can simply set the interval to 1000ms and calculate the number of elapsed seconds.

Comment: Why do you want to trigger something on the exact change of the second by system time? This seems a fairly arbitrary "tick" to time against, would it be any better than simply triggering a function on an interval of 1000ms (1 second)?

Comment: If you are trying to get a notification every second why not just use an interval of 1000ms?

Comment: Yes, it should be a consistent time, e.g. server time. For instance, to display exact server time, for triggering cron jobs in node.js at certain times of the day etc.

Comment: As a sidenote: `typeof NaN === 'number'`.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would need you to sync exactly with the ticking of the system clock.. You would surely get the exact same outcome by simply running the function every second using `setInterval`

Comment: It wouldn't be the _exact_ same outcome as I wouldn't be able to control the time (without fiddling with the triggering of _setInterval_). Is there a way to avoid instantiating _Date_ (so often)?

Answer (score 6):

You're right in that there are no native clock tick events. The most performant while precise way I would approach this issue is using `setTimeout()` and `Date.now()`.

Create a recursive function that calls `setTimeout()` every second. To be precise, make the timeout the duration until the next exact second from that function call. Here's an example.

```
// milliseconds per second
var SECOND = 1000;

function bindClockTick(callback) {
    function tick() {
        var now = Date.now();

        callback(now);

        setTimeout(tick, SECOND - (now % SECOND));
    }

    tick();
}

bindClockTick(function(ms) {
    console.log('tick! milliseconds: '+ ms);
});
```

This uses `Date.now()` instead of creating a new instance of the `Date` class.

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ftYyB/) to test the precision. *The demo uses `new Date()` to easily display the current time, but it can be done with just milliseconds.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to sync with the exact second change; however, here's how I would do it:

```
function clock() {
    var startMs = Date.now(),
        startSecs = Math.floor(startMs / 1000),
        firstOffset = 1000 - startMs % 1000;

    function tick () {
        var ms = Date.now(),
            secs = Math.floor(ms / 1000),
            dSecs = secs - startSecs;
        console.log(dSecs);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        tick();
        setInterval(tick, 1000);
    }, firstOffset);
    tick();
}
clock();
```

Here's what happens:

1. I grab the current time in ms with Date.now()
2. I figure out how many ms until the next second tick (`firstOffset`)
3. I set the initial `setTimeout` to this offset, making sure that it will fire on the next second tick.
4. Now that we are synced with the second tick, `setInterval` with 1000 ms will continue to update every second.

Comment: +1 for _Date.now()_, that already solves half the problem, but the rest is the fiddling that I mentioned. However, it appears there is no other way to create event emitters but to use _setInterval_ or similar.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such emitter; however, the code above should provide the same functionality.